# Having 401 error while fetching user profile using Sanctum with multiguard auth

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

In my laravel app, I have created an authentication system which is consist of 3 kind of users:

1. Internal Admin (using the built in `App\User` class)
2. Customers
3. Employee (Customer's Employee)

I also created a test for each authentication system and it's seems to work perfectly as well as when I do login with the Internal Admin account on the frontend. The problem is, whenever I access the `/api/auth/me` route with `Customer` or `Employee` account, it always gave me a `401 Unauthorized` error even though I have successfully logged in.

Already checked the CORS and I think that's not the problem because I can login and fetch the user profile using the `Internal Admin` account.

Can you guys help me to find what is wrong with my auth system? Please tell me if I made any mistake on the implementation.

Here is my scripts, please have a look. Also, thanks in advance!

`auth.php`

```php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'customer' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customers'
        ],

        'employee' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'employees'
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'customers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Customer::class,
        ],

        'employees' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Employee::class,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

        'customers' => [
            'provider' => 'customers',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

        'employees' => [
            'provider' => 'employees',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

`api.php`

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post('internal/login', 'AuthController@login')->name('internal.login');
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@loginCustomer')->name('customer.login');
    Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout')->middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->name('logout');
    Route::get('me', 'AuthController@me')->middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->name('me');
});
```

`AuthController.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Customer;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Authenticate internal user credentials.
     * 
     * @param \App\Http\Requests\Request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::whereEmail($request->email)->first();

        if (!$user || !Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Authenticate customer credentials.
     * 
     * @param \App\Http\Requests\Request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function loginCustomer(Request $request)
    {
        $customer = Customer::whereEmail($request->email)->first();

        if (!$customer || !Auth::guard('customer')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
        ]);
    }

    public function me()
    {
        return auth()->user()->load('roles');
    }

    /**
     * Logout the user.
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();

        return response()->json([
            'success' => auth()->user()->tokens()->delete()
        ]);
    }
}
```

`User.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasRoles, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * Each user has many customers.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\HasMany
     */
    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Customer::class, 'registrar_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

`Customer.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class Customer extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasRoles, Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'customer';

    /**
     * The attributes that should mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'registrar_id',
        'avatar',
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'suspended',
        'subscription_plan',
        'limit_quota',
        'expired_at',
        'renewed_at',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Each customer belongs to a registrar.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsTo
     */
    public function registrar()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'registrar_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * Each customer has many companies.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\HasMany
     */
    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Company::class, 'owner_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

`InternalUserLogin.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="login-page">
    <v-card id="login-card">
      <template #header>
        <h1>Login Admin</h1>
      </template>
      <form
        :action="$route.path"
        method="POST"
        @submit.prevent="onSubmit"
        @keydown="form.errors.clear($event.target.name)"
      >
        <v-form-group
          id="input-group-email"
          label="Email address"
          label-for="email"
          :has-error="form.errors.has('email')"
          :error-message="form.errors.get('email')"
        >
          <v-form-input
            id="input-email"
            name="email"
            type="email"
            :has-error="form.errors.has('email')"
            placeholder="johndoe@example.com"
            required
            v-model="form.email"
          ></v-form-input>
        </v-form-group>
        <v-form-group id="input-group-password" label="Password" label-for="password">
          <v-form-input
            id="input-password"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            required
            v-model="form.password"
          ></v-form-input>
        </v-form-group>
        <v-button id="login-button" type="submit" :disabled="isBusy || form.errors.any()">
          <template v-if="isBusy">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <v-spinner variant="light" size="sm" class="mr-2"></v-spinner>
              <p class="mb-0">Signing in...</p>
            </div>
          </template>
          <template v-else>Login</template>
        </v-button>
      </form>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: "LoginPage",
    data() {
      return {
        form: new Form({
          email: "",
          password: ""
        }),
        isBusy: false
      };
    },
    methods: {
      onSubmit() {
        this.isBusy = true;

        axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then(resp => {
          this.form
            .post("/api/auth/internal/login")
            .then(resp => {
              this.$store.dispatch("auth/fetchAuth").then(() => {
                this.isBusy = false;
                this.$router.push({ name: "internal.dashboard" });
              });
            })
            .catch(err => (this.isBusy = false));
        });
      }
    }
  };
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .login-page {
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
  }

  #login-card {
    width: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
</style>
```

`CustomerLogin.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="login-page">
    <navbar-public></navbar-public>
    <v-card id="login-card">
      <template #header>
        <h1>Login Customer</h1>
      </template>
      <form
        :action="$route.path"
        method="POST"
        @submit.prevent="onSubmit"
        @keydown="form.errors.clear($event.target.name)"
      >
        <v-form-group
          id="input-group-email"
          label="Email address"
          label-for="email"
          :has-error="form.errors.has('email')"
          :error-message="form.errors.get('email')"
        >
          <v-form-input
            id="input-email"
            name="email"
            type="email"
            :has-error="form.errors.has('email')"
            placeholder="johndoe@example.com"
            required
            v-model="form.email"
          ></v-form-input>
        </v-form-group>
        <v-form-group id="input-group-password" label="Password" label-for="password">
          <v-form-input
            id="input-password"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            required
            v-model="form.password"
          ></v-form-input>
        </v-form-group>
        <v-button id="login-button" type="submit" :disabled="isBusy || form.errors.any()">
          <template v-if="isBusy">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <v-spinner variant="light" size="sm" class="mr-2"></v-spinner>
              <p class="mb-0">Signing in...</p>
            </div>
          </template>
          <template v-else>Login</template>
        </v-button>
      </form>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: "LoginPage",
    data() {
      return {
        form: new Form({
          email: "",
          password: ""
        }),
        isBusy: false
      };
    },
    methods: {
      onSubmit() {
        this.isBusy = true;

        axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then(resp => {
          this.form
            .post("/api/auth/login")
            .then(resp => {
              this.$store.dispatch("auth/fetchAuth").then(() => {
                this.isBusy = false;
                this.$router.push({ name: "dashboard" });
              });
            })
            .catch(err => (this.isBusy = false));
        });
      }
    }
  };
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .login-page {
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
  }

  #login-card {
    width: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
</style>
```

`axios config (bootstrap.js)`

```js
/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.API_URL || 'http://prismahr.test';
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
window.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Comment: are you reaching login() method?

Comment: yes i do sir...

Comment: You meant to have a token, yet I am not seeing it

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum#issuing-api-tokens

Comment: I use session and cookies sir, not using any token at all.

Comment: i don't understand, i think token is just for the mobile apps?

Comment: By having separate BE (RESTfull API) and FE you have to use tokens since BE is stateless

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215694/discussion-between-donny-pratama-and-user3402600).

Comment: did you solved this? I have exactly this problem. I have 2 custom user providers, admin and the default user model, I still got 401 even successfully login

Comment: not yet.. but using `['middleware' => 'auth:my_custom_guardname']` instead of using sanctum for the custom guard seems solved the issue. However, i didn't test the security yet.

Comment: Im in the same boat and would like to know how to do this too. Any updates?